# Camera projection (Projective Geometry - Computer Vision)

Tags: projective-geometry, computer-vision

I am new in Computer Vision. Suppose you have 8 points (players in a basketball court) in a 2D image, that is we know the pixel coordinates of each. I would like to compute camera position w.r.t. the field. We have the actual dimensions of the field. Also, I can write the equations of two or three transversal lines in the field that are parallels lines from top view. With this data can we find a position vector of the camera w.r.t. the field ?

> Any idea on where to read about this ?

Comment: *Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision* by Hartley & Zisserman is a good resource.

Comment: Thank you!, Excellent :)